# Adding additional unique Row ID to existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below code where I assign an unique ID to each row which contains a current code and a previous code. It seems to be working fine but my question is if I have an updated file with new codes, how do I resume the unique ID from where it was left off?

For example, how do I populate the below ID highlighted in yellow if I add these additional row?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVhmG.png)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PI_Key_Create_Update]   AS
BEGIN
Truncate Table RB_PI_Key_Assign
Truncate Table RB_PI_Key_Link

INSERT INTO RB_PI_Key_Assign
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RB_Code_L) AS PI_Key
, RB_Code_L
, RB_Code_L_P
FROM Stage_RB_Previous

INSERT INTO RB_PI_Key_Link
SELECT 
  a.PI_Key
, b.PI_Key as PI_KEY_P
, a.RB_Code_L
, a.RB_Code_L_P

FROM RB_PI_Key_Assign a LEFT JOIN RB_PI_Key_Assign b ON (a.RB_Code_L_P=b.RB_Code_L) 

END
```

Thanks

Comment: why does your id field not identity seeded so you don't have to maintain them manually?

Answer (score 0):

first and foremost this type of columns should be identity seeded or autoincrement. You don't need to maintain them.

There is nothing special if you have them manually updated for no reason at all.

Comment: Thanks maSTA. I want the unique ID to stay with the row for its life. If I update the table but the rows are in different order, will the identity id change?

Comment: The identity wont change and it will auto increment if you change the behaviour of this field. It will only reset back to 1 if you truncate the table. To give it a clean slate truncate table and insert rows according to your sequence